# double getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having this problem where I'm unable to narrow the span of getElementsByTagName.

this is what I'm doing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
{
    var t = document.getElementById("t");
    var x = t.getElementsByTagName("table");
    //var f = x.getElementsByTagName("td");
    alert(x.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="t">
    <table class="x">
        <td class="f">
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many input elements?">
</body>
</html>
```

the above works, brings back 1.

though when I change this.

```
var f = x.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(f.length);
```

it breaks the script.

how I'm I able to narrow it when I'm unable to use 2 TagNames?

**UPDATE: my bad, I realised after posting this that it has to have [0] after the var.**

```
var t = document.getElementById("t");
var x = t.getElementsByTagName("table");
var f = x[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
var u = f[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
alert(f.length);
alert(u[0].className);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `getElementsByTagName` always returns an array, even if there is only one element.

If you do `var f = x[0].getElementsByTagName("td");` it should work properly.

Comment: yea, that worked for me, it had totally slipped my mind at the time being, even when I knew it was an array.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no `getElementsByTagName` function on a node list object.  That is, your first call to `getElementById()` returns a DOM element, so calling `getElementsByTagName()` from that result works. However, that second call returns a node list (an HTMLCollection), which has no such method.

If you want to accumulate a list of all `<td>` elements inside all tables, you'll have to code that up explicitly. Iterate through the results of the first call (the list of `<table>` elements), and accumulate the results of calling `getElementsByTagName("td")` on each element of each list.  (The elements of the node lists are DOM elements, so that'll work).